# Python Eve 0.5. How to find documents which contain substring in 'name' field'?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve, flask-mongoengine

I could not find any information in the docs how to find documents which contain substring in document field, in my case it is 'name' field. All solutions which I was able to find on the Internet didn't work for me, I see bad request error. May be the problem that I use version 0.5 of the framework and it is unstable and buggy now? (but I need embedded documents in API responses, it seems that 0.4 doesn't support this) Could anybody assist me regarding the issue?
Also I am wonder how to make requests something like:

```
documents.find(name__contains='est' or speciality='dentist')
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `$regex` is not blacklisted in `MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST` (it is by default), then query with:

```
http://localhost:5000/documents?where={"name": {"$regex": "est"}}
```

with `$or`:

```
http://localhost:5000/documents?where={"$or": [{"name": {"$regex": "est"}}, {"speciality": "dentist"}]}
```